# Get geolocation from Flutter application when the app is terminated

Tags: android, ios, flutter, operating-system

I am developing a Flutter app that needs to access the user's location even when the app is closed on both iOS and Android.

My primary concern is not when the app is running in the background but rather when the operating system terminates the app or puts it to sleep. Is there a way to receive the user's geolocation under these circumstances? I don't need real-time GPS tracking from the user when the app is terminated, but rather periodic updates, maybe every 1-3 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, not happening.  You'll have to rethink why you need it and find some other way.

Comment: You can look at significant location change on iOS

Comment: @Paulw11 I am creating an app, where people can receive alerts for when's there are some incidents close by the user. I am also creating a small bluetooth device which will connect to the phone automatically when the user sits in the car, however is it possible to make a suspended app or terminated app to wake up if it connects to a Bluetooth device?

Comment: It sounds like significant location change service is what you want for iOS. As for Bluetooth, that is going to be platform specific, but yes you can do that in iOS. Search for the core Bluetooth programming guide and read about background mode and state restoration.